# Sending signal to certain (grand-...)grandchildren

Tags: c, signals, fork

Is there a nice way to send a SIGUSR to a grandchild directly?
E.g. I have some process tree:

```
     0
    / \
   1   2
        \
         3
```

and need to send a signal from `0` to `3`.

I know I could save child's pid after forking and the use it with `kill()` like

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) { 
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) { /* grandchild */ }
    savepid = pid;
}

...

kill(savepid,sig);
```

but then I'd have to use shared memory to make those variable globally visible, which is not allowed in my homework :)

Comment: use a `pipe()` to comunicate the `pid3` to `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct communication between parent and grandchildren. The usual approach here is having the grandchild to store its PID somewhere on the filesystem (say, in /var/lib/myapp/grandchild.pid) and reading it back in the parent.

You can also use process groups on Linux, but they offer a coarse-grained approach.

Comment: You can also send a signal to the first child (parent of the grandchild), and have that get send down then from the child.

Answer (score 1):

**dunno if this works flawlessly, but the MAIN idea is here**

```
int fd[2];  /*write(fd[1],buffer,strlen)
            / read(fd[0],buffer2,SIZE)*/
pid_t cpid,savepid;

if(pipe(fd)==-1){
    perror("pipe");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if((cpid=fork())<0){/*  FORK INIT FOR CHILD  */
    printf("\n\tFORK ERROR\n");
    exit(1);
}
if(cpid==0){        /*process CHILD*/

    if((cpid=fork())<0){/*  FORK INIT FOR GRANDCHILD */
        printf("\n\tFORK ERROR\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(cpid==0){        /*process GRANDCHILD*/
        close(fd[0]);
        if((write(fd[1],(char*)pid,strlen(final2)))<0){
            perror("\n\tWRITE ERROR");
        }
        /********CODE******/
        close(fd[1]);
    }else{                  /*process CHILD*/
        /********CODE******/

    }
}else{                  /*process PARENT*/
    close(fd[1]);
    if((read(fd[0],(char*)savepid,NN))<0){
        perror("\n\tREAD ERROR");   
    }
    /********CODE******/
    kill(savepid,SIGKILL);
    /*code parent*/
    wait(NULL);
    close(fd[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the `pipe()` example, but I'll probably just use pidfiles for now.